# Measure SVG text dimensions without rendering

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to calculate a text's width before rendering it (for the purpose of laying out the texts). Using `getBBox()` works on Chrome browsers but breaks using Firefox (`NS_ERROR`).

What is the suggested way to calculate SVG text dimensions without rendering it?

Comment: What's wrong with rendering then measuring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably used the style `display: none`.  Try `visibility: hidden` instead and `.getBBox()` should work.