# Measure generated svg server side

Tags: svg, text

Am working on a project where complicated visuals are generated on a server in svg to be rendered on a browser.  One problem I'm having involves text layout. 
 In some cases, I dynamically generate some text in an svg text element, but need to know what the size it will be when rendered.

There are some other stack overflow questions that are somewhat similar:

[Measuring dimensions of svg elements in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51703422/measuring-dimensions-of-svg-elements-in-angular)

[Measure SVG text dimensions without rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540212/measure-svg-text-dimensions-without-rendering)

The difference here, though, is that those are done in the web browser, I'm trying to do this on the server, specifically in a .NET Core application running in a docker container, which would ideally provide only a minimal environment.

Thanks so much for help in advance.

Comment: Please describe why you need the measurement server-side. If it is for the layout of something that only the client will render, that is always a job for the client side.

Comment: I entirely understand your reasoning.  It's a legacy system, the web experience was hacked together by running an app that was designed to run locally on the server instead, and communicating graphical output via svg.  A solution to the problem of measuring svg would be valuable.  Trying to get more of the app to run in the browser is attractive, but probably a more expensive/longer term project.

Comment: Let me rephrase: in the browser, measuring the rendered text is one line of Javascript, while on the server it is complicated guesswork (because you are guessing, but not knowing, which font will be used, how wide each individual glyph is, how partial pixel values are rounded, whether the text will be repositioned for antialiasing optimisation...). So, as long as the measurement can in any sensible way be done client-side, that will always be preferable. - That said, maybe this will give you a rough estimate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426768